# Instagram API change without warning?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I know that as of June 2016, Instagram are going to vet who can use their API, but we've noticed something has changed early.

Does anyone have any information on how the vetting process is going to work?

Comment: Sounds like a question to put to Instagram directly...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Instagram platform update](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update).

> **Simplified platform policy**
>
> We’ve updated our Platform Policy to
>   explicitly list the use cases we will support moving forward. These
>   include apps and services that:
>
> Help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps, such as
>   apps that let you print your photos and import an Instagram photo as a
>   profile picture. Help brands and advertisers understand and manage
>   their audience, develop their content strategy, and get digital rights
>   to media. Established apps in this space may apply for our newly
>   announced Instagram Partner Program. Help broadcasters and publishers
>   discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media using
>   web embeds. You can read the full terms here.
>
> **New review process and sandbox**
>
> We will begin reviewing new and
>   existing apps before granting full API access starting December 3,
>   2015. Existing apps have until June 1, 2016 to submit and be approved.
>
> We are also launching Sandbox Mode, which will let you privately build
>   and test your apps using Instagram’s APIs as your app is being
>   reviewed.